# How to obtain distinct values over Django Query Set?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Gender(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    genders = models.ManyToManyField(Gender)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**view.py:**

```
def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(genders=1)

    categories = Category.objects.filter(post__genders=1)
                                 .exclude(post=None).order_by('-sort')
```

Why do I get the same category 3 times if there are 3 posts where gender is equal to 1?? I only need the category 1 time i my select like "select distinct" - how can I do so??

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Did you try attaching a [`.distinct()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) to the queryset?

```
categories = Category.objects.filter(post__genders=1).exclude(post=
      None).order_by('-sort').distinct()
```